# OWAにOffice365ファイルハンドラ拡張技術を適用する方法

Tags: visual-studio

Overview of Office 365 file handlers（https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/using-cross-suite-apps）のページを見て、MSのファイル形式ではないファイル形式のものでも、"SharePoint Online"や"One Drive for Business"上で

1. アイコン表示
2. プレビュー
3. 閲覧や編集

が可能になる技術があるということを知りました。これらの技術情報の公開に非常にワクワクしているのですが、OWAでもこれらのことができる技術があるのかどうかを現在探しています。
何か良い方法があればご教示下さい。宜しくお願い致します。